Can we share a text from one device to the other via NFC
I've been experimenting with nfc_manager to enable NFC tag reading and writing in my application. My goal is to facilitate message sharing between two devices when they come into contact via NFC. Despite attempting various solutions, I've been unsuccessful so far. If anyone has successfully implemented this feature or can provide any helpful blogs or references, I'd greatly appreciate the assistance.
Additionally, I'm curious about the feasibility of connecting iOS and Android devices via NFC for this purpose.

Does this answer your question? How to use Android device to expose a URL to other phones via NFC?

NFC is not really suitable for data sharing especially if it involves iOS devices, use WiFi Direct or bluetooth instead. There is a method that involves there being at least one Android device out of the pair but it is not simple.
